# Understanding dependent lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde

How do I tell the compiler that one lifetime must outlive another?

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Tokens<'a> {
    buffer: String,
    list: Vec<Token<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Token<'a> {
    term: &'a str,
}
```

yields

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/pipeline/tokenizers/test.rs:6:5
  |
3 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
  |                     ----------- lifetime `'de` defined here
4 | pub struct Tokens<'a> {
  |                   -- lifetime `'a` defined here
5 |     buffer: String,
6 |     list: Vec<Token<'a>>,
  |     ^^^^ requires that `'de` must outlive `'a`
  |
  = help: consider adding the following bound: `'de: 'a`
```

In the code above, the token.term: &str will always refer to a slice of tokens.buffer. I'm not sure how to specify that relationship. I'm also not sure how to add the requested bound.

Will this even work? If so, what's the magic syntax?

Comment: Two similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692768/how-to-derive-serdedeserialize-for-a-struct-with-members-with-lifetimes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394620/why-can-serde-not-derive-deserialize-for-a-struct-containing-only-a-path. Though I'm not inclined to close this one as a dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the attribute, `#[serde(borrow)]`, which makes the generated `Deserialize` implementation borrow the data.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Tokens<'a> {
    buffer: String,
    #[serde(borrow)]
    list: Vec<Token<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Token<'a> {
    term: &'a str,
}
```

See:

- [Borrowing Data in a Derived impl](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#borrowing-data-in-a-derived-impl)
- [Serde field attributes (borrow)](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#borrow)

Comment: Thank you. This works. Is it necessary or possible to require that Token depend on Tokens.buffer?

Comment: @ccleve One: no, serde will not make `list` refer to data in `buffer`, you would need a custom `Deserialize` implementation. Two: that would be creating a self-referential struct which has a whole host of problems, see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](/q/32300132/2189130).

Answer (score 4):

You can't add constraints to a `derive` implementation. You *could* write the entire `Deserialize` implementation yourself and put the constraint in the usual place. But fortunately, `serde` [thought of this use case](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#borrowing-data-in-a-derived-impl). If you indicate to `serde` that the data should be borrowed *from* the deserializer, it will put the constraint in for you.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Tokens<'a> {
    buffer: String,
    #[serde(borrow)]
    list: Vec<Token<'a>>,
}
```